# sqoop import success but hive show tables can't see table

Tags: hadoop, import, hive, sqoop

env:sqoop-1.4.2  hadoop-1.0.4  hive-0.9.0

import cmd:
./bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/metrics  --username root -password 1023   --table Visit     --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table hivevisit2  --hive-home  /home/hadoop/hive/

files exist in hdfs:
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup          0 2013-02-19 10:36 /user/hive/warehouse/hivevisit2

but show tables in hive,table hivevisit2 doesnot exist

lt seems that when exe cmd "sqoop -hive-import" ,lt will create the table automaticly,but why when l cann't see the table

if i re-execute cmd 
"./bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/metrics  --username root -password 1023   --table Visit     --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table hivevisit2  --hive-home  /home/hadoop/hive/"

error shows "Error in metadata: AlreadyExistsException(message:Table hivevisit2 already exists)"

could anyone tell me the solution how to automatic create table during hive import

Answer (score 1):

try to run sqoop command and hive command from the same location.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using as a hive data store backend? Hive by default will create embedded derby data store for it's metastore in current working directory. Thus when running Hive and Sqoop from different directories you might get different table spaces. I would recommend to configure Hive to use some database backed data store (MySQL, PostgreSQL) and configure both Hive and Sqoop to use that.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you have to create a schema like that /user/hive/warehouse/*mySchema.db*. 
    It's just a directory with name **mySchema.db**
2. Then you can import the desired table under the schema with the following command:

   sqoop import 
   --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/metrics 
   --username root --password 1023 --table Visit
   --hive-import --create-hive-table  --hive-table **mySchema**.hivevisit2